# perl regexp for mail address

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, logging, exim

ive got some trouble with writting regex for this lines in exim log

```
 1. 2011-05-12 11:30:26 1QKRHt-0001aD-Vd => mail <mail@mail.example.com> F=<root@example.com> bla bla 
 2. 2011-04-22 12:01:31 1QDCF0-0002ss-Nw => /var/mail/mail <root@mail.mealstrom.org.ua> F=<root@example.com> bla bla 
 3. 2011-05-12 11:29:01 1QKRGU-0001a5-Ok => mail@mail.example.com F=<root@example.com> bla bla
```

and i want to put to variable this **mail@mail.example.com** in one regexp. ive tryed to use logic lile this:  *find last string before 'F=', seperated by whitespaces and can be locked in **< >***

Can you help me to write this logic?

Comment: If you want to validate e-mail addresses according to [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt?number=822) it is [not easy at all, a good regex is awesomely long](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
# the line should be in variable $line
if ($line =~ /.*?\s+<?(\S+?)>?\s+F=/) {
  # ...
}
```

And then it is a good idea to validate your match with [Mail-RFC822-Address](http://search.cpan.org/~pdwarren/Mail-RFC822-Address-0.3/Address.pm) perl module, so the full code could be:

```
use Mail::RFC822::Address qw(valid);

# the line should be in variable $line
if ($line =~ /.*?\s+<?(\S+?)>?\s+F=/) {
  if (valid($1)) {
    # ...
  }
}
```

Comment: ive used this package to validate emails. and yours regexp works. you have contributed to this project :D https://github.com/mealstrom/plp2sql/ 

the emails are valid cos they are already in log.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
/(?<=<)\S*(?=>\s*F=)/
```

The `(?<= xxx )` syntax is a lookbehind assertion, and the `(?= xxx )` is a lookahead assertion.

*this will not check the validity of the e-mail address*, just extract that part of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Email Validation Regex

```
\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b
```

It will extract an email from anywhere.

I hope this RFC2822 one posts correctly.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)\*@(?:\[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.)+\[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]\*[a-z0-9])?
```

Comment: I think this is missing some square brackets in the part after the `@` to define character classes

Comment: It wouldnt seem to post, kept getting cut for some reason. I added another one instead.

Comment: it is non standard. For example `foo+bar@gmail.com` is a valid e-mail address, and you do not support it. See [this !](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: I have managed to get the RFC2822 one posted. Took a bit but got it to display on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the measure, [Email::Valid](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aValid) is.